# Accessing only second sub-element from json object in r

Tags: json, r, rjson, rjsonio

This is a sample rows from json object.

```
row1)   {"results":[{"address_components":[{"long_name":"16","short_name":"16","types":["street_number"]},{"long_name":"Bhagwan Tatyasaheb Kawade Road","short_name":"BT Kawde Road","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Palmgrove Society","short_name":"Palmgrove Society","types":["neighborhood","political"]},{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Ghorpadi","short_name":"Ghorpadi","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"411001","short_name":"411001","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"16, BT Kawade Road, Palmgrove Society, Uday Baug, Ghorpadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411001, India","geometry":{"location":{"lat":18.5132611,"lng":73.907346},"location_type":"ROOFTOP","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5146100802915,"lng":73.90869498029151},"southwest":{"lat":18.51191211970849,"lng":73.90599701970851}}},"place_id":"ChIJo1QsU7nBwjsRiewRdiNc2i4","types":["street_address"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","short_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Jambhulkar Mala, Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}},"location":{"lat":18.508659,"lng":73.9029138},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJJ0lCDMfBwjsRrPmUq2ZOxd8","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}},"location":{"lat":18.4828904,"lng":73.9016832},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}}},"place_id":"ChIJ8TQ7l8LBwjsROUGpMh25HMw","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Prabhag 36","short_name":"Prabhag 36","types":["administrative_area_level_3","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}},"location":{"lat":18.5204303,"lng":73.8567437},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}}},"place_id":"ChIJARFGZy6_wjsRQ-Oenb9DjYI","types":["locality","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"411040","short_name":"411040","types":["postal_code"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra 411040, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}},"location":{"lat":18.492095,"lng":73.90017759999999},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-64DzdvBwjsRKzv08MBrn18","types":["postal_code"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.16309},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}},"location":{"lat":18.6832564,"lng":74.0300122},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.1447465},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}}},"place_id":"ChIJQ97RPE_AwjsR5zbDDbo3wHI","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":22.028441,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}},"location":{"lat":19.7514798,"lng":75.7138884},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":22.0279091,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-dacnB7EzzsRtk_gS5IiLxs","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39535869999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.4626999,"lng":68.1097}},"location":{"lat":20.593684,"lng":78.96288},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39498069999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.7535159,"lng":68.16288519999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc","types":["country","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["bus_station","establishment","point_of_interest","transit_station"]},{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Ghorpadi","short_name":"Ghorpadi","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"411001","short_name":"411001","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Uday Baug, Ghorpadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411001, India","geometry":{"location":{"lat":18.510892,"lng":73.906956},"location_type":"GEOMETRIC_CENTER","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5122409802915,"lng":73.9083049802915},"southwest":{"lat":18.5095430197085,"lng":73.90560701970848}}},"place_id":"ChIJ5YdfqcDBwjsR5VJutWLCsfA","types":["bus_station","establishment","point_of_interest","transit_station"]}],"status":"OK"}
row2) {"results":[{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Canal Road","short_name":"Canal Rd","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Empress Garden View Society","short_name":"Empress Garden View Society","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_3"]},{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Ghorpadi","short_name":"Ghorpadi","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"411001","short_name":"411001","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Canal Rd, Empress Garden View Society, Uday Baug, Ghorpadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411001, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510637,"lng":73.9070137},"southwest":{"lat":18.5102785,"lng":73.9016839}},"location":{"lat":18.510445,"lng":73.90438309999999},"location_type":"GEOMETRIC_CENTER","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5118067302915,"lng":73.9070137},"southwest":{"lat":18.50910876970849,"lng":73.9016839}}},"place_id":"ChIJ88lKe8fBwjsRCRKukkS6-nM","types":["route"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","short_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Jambhulkar Mala, Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}},"location":{"lat":18.508659,"lng":73.9029138},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJJ0lCDMfBwjsRrPmUq2ZOxd8","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}},"location":{"lat":18.4828904,"lng":73.9016832},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}}},"place_id":"ChIJ8TQ7l8LBwjsROUGpMh25HMw","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Prabhag 36","short_name":"Prabhag 36","types":["administrative_area_level_3","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}},"location":{"lat":18.5204303,"lng":73.8567437},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}}},"place_id":"ChIJARFGZy6_wjsRQ-Oenb9DjYI","types":["locality","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"411040","short_name":"411040","types":["postal_code"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra 411040, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}},"location":{"lat":18.492095,"lng":73.90017759999999},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-64DzdvBwjsRKzv08MBrn18","types":["postal_code"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.16309},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}},"location":{"lat":18.6832564,"lng":74.0300122},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.1447465},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}}},"place_id":"ChIJQ97RPE_AwjsR5zbDDbo3wHI","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":22.028441,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}},"location":{"lat":19.7514798,"lng":75.7138884},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":22.0279091,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-dacnB7EzzsRtk_gS5IiLxs","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39535869999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.4626999,"lng":68.1097}},"location":{"lat":20.593684,"lng":78.96288},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39498069999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.7535159,"lng":68.16288519999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc","types":["country","political"]}],"status":"OK"}
row3) {"results":[{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Canal Road","short_name":"Canal Rd","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Empress Garden View Society","short_name":"Empress Garden View Society","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_3"]},{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Ghorpadi","short_name":"Ghorpadi","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"411001","short_name":"411001","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Canal Rd, Empress Garden View Society, Uday Baug, Ghorpadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411001, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510637,"lng":73.9070137},"southwest":{"lat":18.5102785,"lng":73.9016839}},"location":{"lat":18.510445,"lng":73.90438309999999},"location_type":"GEOMETRIC_CENTER","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5118067302915,"lng":73.9070137},"southwest":{"lat":18.50910876970849,"lng":73.9016839}}},"place_id":"ChIJ88lKe8fBwjsRCRKukkS6-nM","types":["route"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","short_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Jambhulkar Mala, Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}},"location":{"lat":18.508659,"lng":73.9029138},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJJ0lCDMfBwjsRrPmUq2ZOxd8","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}},"location":{"lat":18.4828904,"lng":73.9016832},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}}},"place_id":"ChIJ8TQ7l8LBwjsROUGpMh25HMw","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Prabhag 36","short_name":"Prabhag 36","types":["administrative_area_level_3","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}},"location":{"lat":18.5204303,"lng":73.8567437},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}}},"place_id":"ChIJARFGZy6_wjsRQ-Oenb9DjYI","types":["locality","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"411040","short_name":"411040","types":["postal_code"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra 411040, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}},"location":{"lat":18.492095,"lng":73.90017759999999},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-64DzdvBwjsRKzv08MBrn18","types":["postal_code"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.16309},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}},"location":{"lat":18.6832564,"lng":74.0300122},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.1447465},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}}},"place_id":"ChIJQ97RPE_AwjsR5zbDDbo3wHI","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":22.028441,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}},"location":{"lat":19.7514798,"lng":75.7138884},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":22.0279091,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-dacnB7EzzsRtk_gS5IiLxs","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39535869999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.4626999,"lng":68.1097}},"location":{"lat":20.593684,"lng":78.96288},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39498069999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.7535159,"lng":68.16288519999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc","types":["country","political"]}],"status":"OK"}
```

To access address componet I used the following code

```
dat <- lapply(readLines("D:/Deepesh/All files/example1.json"), fromJSON)
res = lapply(dat, function(x) {

  lapply(x[["results"]], function(y) {

    do.call(rbind, lapply(y[['address_components']], function(z) {

      if (is.null(z)) {

        c(rep(NA, 3))}

      else {

        c(z[['types']][[1]], z[['long_name']], z[['short_name']])
      }
    }))
  })
})
```

this gives me following output

```
> head(res)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
      [,1]                        [,2]                          [,3]               
 [1,] "street_number"             "16"                          "16"               
 [2,] "route"                     "parkwsy"                     "psk"    
 [3,] "neighborhood"           "Palmgrove Soci"               "Palmgrove"
 [4,] "political"               "Uday Baug"                      "Uday Baug"        
 [5,] "political"                "Ghorpadi"                       "Ghorpadi"         
 [6,] "locality"                  "Pune"                           "Pune"             


[[1]][[2]]
     [,1]                          [,2]              [,3]             
[1,] "political"                   "Jambhulkar Mala" "Jambhulkar Mala"
[2,] "political"                   "Wanowrie"        "Wanowrie"       
[3,] "locality"                    "Pune"            "Pune"           

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
    [,1]                          [,2]                          [,3]                         
 [1,] "route"                    "Canal Road"                  "Canal Rd"                   
 [2,] "political"               "Empress Garden Soc"           "Empress"
 [3,] "political"                "Uday Baug"                   "Uday Baug"                  
 [4,] "political"                "Ghorpadi"                    "Ghorpadi"                   
 [5,] "locality"                  "Pune"                        "Pune"                       


[[2]][[2]]
     [,1]                     [,2]              [,3]             
[1,] "political"          "Jambhulkar Mala" "Jambhulkar Mala"
[2,] "political"            "Wanowrie"        "Wanowrie"       
[3,] "locality"              "Pune"            "Pune"           

[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
      [,1]                          [,2]                     [,3]                         
 [1,] "route"                       "Canal Road"           "Canal Rd"                   
 [2,] "political"                   "Empress view "         "Em"
 [3,] "political"                   "Uday Baug"            "Uday Baug"                  
 [4,] "political"                   "Ghorpadi"             "Ghorpadi"                   
 [5,] "locality"                    "Pune"                  "Pune"                       

[[3]][[2]]
     [,1]                   [,2]              [,3]             
[1,] "political"         "Jambhulkar Mala" "Jambhulkar Mala"
[2,] "political"         "Wanowrie"        "Wanowrie"       
[3,] "locality"          "Pune"            "Pune"
```

Everything is working fine except that I'm expecting "sublocalities" as output values rather than "political" in O/P fron the line **"{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},"**

It is not able to take "sublocality" from `["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]}` instead it is taking first element i.e "political"
Any suggestion on what changes should be made in order to acheive the expected output.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can use the package jsonlite to read and explore your file ? i don't know how it works but you can check

Comment: @deepesh, as I explained in your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45607736/extracting-json-data-from-google-geocoding-api-in-r/45611220?noredirect=1#comment78214528_45611220) the **"types"** array varies in length. The first row has 2 items ("neighborhood","political") and the second and third rows has 3 items ("political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"). The **z[['types']][[1]]** of the nested lapply() function picks the first item of the array. By changing to **z[['types']][[2]]** it will pick the "sublocality" from the 2nd and 3rd rows and "political" from 1st row.

Comment: Yes that the problem is when ever "("political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2")" this situation comes it should access "sublocality_level_2". And also if consecutively ("political","sublocality","sublocality_level_3") comes it should access "sublocality_level_3". z[['types']][[2]] cannot be make generic right?

Comment: @deepesh, if you know in advance the exact names that the **Type** column should take (lets say it will only take  "neighborhood", "sublocality", "route", etc.) in your output data.frame, then you can update your question with a vector including those specific types. Then I'll modify the lapply() function to return either one of these values each time or NA (missing value) in case that the value does not appear in the given vector.

Comment: ok I'll do that

Comment: @Impros Updated the previous post  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45607736/extracting-json-data-from-google-geocoding-api-in-r"